# Android Studio - How to send data from MainActivity.xml to Service?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When creating the app, I encountered one problem. I have quite a large number of checkboxes, each of which is responsible for turning on/off a specific sound. I made service with MediaPlayer, but I do not know how to send the checkbox value "checked" from MainActivity.xml to the service.

MainActivity.xml:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));

    CheckBox soundCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sound1cb);
    CheckBox sound2CheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sound2cb);
    CheckBox sound3CheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sound3cb);
    CheckBox sound4CheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sound4cb);
    CheckBox sound5CheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sound5cb);
```

Answer (score 0):

add your data on intent,

```
intent.putExtra("key" , "value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to communicate from Activity to Service (and possibly other way around), you need to use [BoundService](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services) . This will let you get service Binder in Activity, and then call service methods... it's big simplification, but I think diving into that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must first this line to activity

```
startService(new Intent(activity, SampleService.class).putExtra("key", "value"))
```

and add this line to service for get data in onCreate or onStartCommand methud

```
intent.getStringExtra("key")
```